# FFMPEG version 0.6.5 video rotate

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am writing a php code to rotate the video using ffmpeg 0.6.5 (This is the version installed on the client's web-server). Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any documentation for this version of ffmpeg.

Here is the command for ffmpeg I have written using few references I could find online.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -vfilters 'rotate=90' -i /hsphere/local/home/testdomain.com/ffmpeg-php-class-master/examples/media/nsa.mp4 /hsphere/local/home/testdomain.com/ffmpeg-php-class-master/examples/media/output.mp4
```

The error for this command -

array(18) { [0]=> string(67) "FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers" [1]=> string(74) " built on Jan 29 2012 23:55:02 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)" [2]=> string(649) " configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab" [3]=> string(35) " libavutil 50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1" [4]=> string(35) " libavcodec 52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2" [5]=> string(35) " libavformat 52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2" [6]=> string(35) " libavdevice 52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0" [7]=> string(35) " libavfilter 1.19. 0 / 1.19. 0" [8]=> string(35) " libswscale 0.11. 0 / 0.11. 0" [9]=> string(35) " libpostproc 51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0" [10]=> string(135) "Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/hsphere/local/home/testdomain.com/ffmpeg-php-class-master/examples/media/nsa.mp4':" [11]=> string(11) " Metadata:" [12]=> string(26) " major_brand : mp42" [13]=> string(23) " minor_version : 0" [14]=> string(39) " compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1" [15]=> string(60) " Duration: 00:00:11.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2163 kb/s" [16]=> string(124) " Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2160 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc" [17]=> string(24) "Unrecognized option 'vfilters'" } int(1)

The main part of the error is the last line - [17]=> string(24) "Unrecognized option 'vfilters'" } int(1)

I have tried using *-vf* as well instead of *vfilters* and I get the same error.

Could someone please help me with any pointers? I am open to any other technique to rotate video orientation. I have to rotate and save the video in the correct orientation.

Thank you!

Comment: 0.6.5 is very old and unsupported. You're just wasting your time using something so outdated. Also, option placement matters: you're trying to use `-vfilters` as an input option.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - Thanks for the input. Any alternatives you would like to suggest?

Comment: You can upgrade. The simplest method is to [download a `ffmpeg` binary](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (kernels 2.6.32+) and point your script to it. Or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).

Comment: You can kind of find documentation by "building" or "looking at" that version: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/v0.6.1 but might not be easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned the idea of using ffmpeg as my hosting server wouldn't support the latest version. Instead I used native android and ios libraries to determine the orientation of the video and rotate it if required automatically before uploading it to the server. Also the native libraries support in compression on the device before uploading.

As @LordNeckbeard in the comments of my query pointed out, it was not worth wasting time working on the older version of ffmpeg.